# Proof for a subgroup composed of a sequence of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I am stuck trying to prove the following problem:

For a group $G$ let $\{H_i\}$ (where $i$ is a positive integer) be a sequence of $G$'s subgroups. For $i \geq 1$ $H_i \subset H_{i+1}$ and $H_i \neq H_{i+1}$. $H$ equals the union of all $H_i$.

I am trying to prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ but is not cyclic.

It seems obvious that the union of any sequence of subgroups must itself be a subgroup, but I do not see how the cyclic aspect comes into play (or how to explicitly prove that $H$ is a subgroup beyond the promise method).

Comment: It cannot be cyclic, because cyclic groups satisfy the ascending chain condition on subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $H$ is a subgroup in the usual way: show that it is nonempty and that if $a,b \in H$ then $ab^{-1} \in H$. Clearly $H$ Is nonempty since it contains $H_1$. If $a,b \in H$, then $a \in H_i$ and $b \in H_j$ for some $i,j$. Therefore $a,b \in H_m$ where $m = \max(i,j)$. Since $H_m$ is a subgroup, it also contains $ab^{-1}$ and therefore so does $H$ since the latter contains $H_m$.

Suppose $H$ is cyclic. Then it is generated by some element $x$, which must be contained in some $H_i$. But then $H_i$ also contains $\langle x \rangle = H$. This is impossible because $H_{i+1}$ contains elements of $H$ which are not in $H_i$.

Comment: Is $a, b \in H_m$ since $H_i \subset H_j$

Comment: @math1337 If $i \leq j$ then $H_i \subseteq H_j = H_m$. If $j \leq i$ then $H_j \subseteq H_i = H_m$. Either way, $a$ and $b$ are both in $H_m$. (Note that $H_m$ is simply whichever of $H_i$ or $H_j$ has a larger index. The point of this is to find one subgroup which contains both $a$ and $b$.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.